# Get Class and Apply another class

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML:

```
<div id="tagCloud">
<a class="5" title="1 records" href="tags=Battleship">Battleship</a>
<a class="4" title="1 records" href="tags=Cabbage">Cabbage</a>
etc...
```

I want to take the class value, and convert it to a word.

So if class = 5 append class five?

Comment: How high can classes go? i.e. will you potentially have `<a class="678" href="#"></a>`?

Comment: Class will only ever be 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace all classes called 5:

```
$(".5").removeClass("5").addClass("five");
```

If you want to automate it for any class with a digit name, then it is going to be more difficult. I would make a [custom selector](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-jquery-selectors.html) that could pick out classes with only numbers (based on [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)), then use [each](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) to loop through and find out what that number was, for each element, and then create a function for [translating a number into english](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm?inum=768&rnum=), and then add that class. Note that this wouldn't be terribly fast though.

Comment: This is the literal way to handle the case for 5 / five, but doesn't generalize, which is what I think @danit is asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum class number, you can do this (with max being 10):

```
var nums = new Array("zero","one","two","three","four","five","six",
                     "seven","eight","nine","ten");
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
{
    $("." + i).addClass(nums[i]);
}
```

I don't know of any way to more dynamically get the text of a number, but something may exist.